# WPF GridSplitter strange behavior when Column Width="Auto"

Tags: wpf, column-width, gridsplitter

I have pretty simple layout, look:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0"
            BorderBrush="Red"
            BorderThickness="2">
        <!-- Any picture-->
        <Image Source="/Resources/PreviewTest.png"></Image>
    </Border>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" 
                    Width="5"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"></GridSplitter>
    <Expander Grid.Column="2"
                ExpandDirection="Left"
                BorderBrush="RoyalBlue"
                BorderThickness="2">
        <!-- Any picture-->
        <Image Source="/Resources/PreviewTest.png"></Image>    
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

The problem: when I'm dragging `GridSplitter` to left, right column goes out from window border as shown on animation. I found that it happens when width of third column is set as "Auto" (`Width="Auto"`). If I set `Width="*"` `GridSplitter` works fine and third `Column` doesn't go out from window border. So why when `Width="Auto"` it happens?

[image: Demonstration]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that one of your `ColumnDefinition`s is set to `Auto`. What is happening is that when the first column reaches its `MinWidth` value, it can't get any smaller. However, if you keep moving the `GridSlitter`, then the right column has to grow. Seeing as you let it grow to any size, you get your current problem.

All that you need to do to fix it is to set the right `ColumnDefinition.Width` property to the `*` value as well. In this way, it can't grow out of the `Grid` any more. If you need to, you can control the end sizes of the columns using the `ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth` property. Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="50" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
        <Image Source="/Resources/PreviewTest.png" />
    </Border>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment" />
    <Expander Grid.Column="2" ExpandDirection="Left" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" BorderThickness="2">
        <Image Source="/Resources/PreviewTest.png" />
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```